# Rsyslog's RELP format; experience?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

1) In your experience, does rsyslog's RELP log transfer format require a significant amount of resources over what plain TCP syslog transfer would use?  (cpu, disk i/o, network)

2) IYHO, is TCP syslog transfer so unreliable?

Now that I'm asking, how would you compare these two against UDP syslog transfer?

Thanks!